# OpenGL light with object rotation

Tags: opengl, rotation, light

I am trying to rotate dodecahedron with simple light.

The code in the display function is this:

```c
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.5f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.75f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.4);
GLfloat black[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
GLfloat blue[] = { 0, 1, 1, 1 };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, black);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, blue);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, blue);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

glTranslatef(0, 0, -50);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 1.0, 0);
glutSolidDodecahedron();
```

The `angle` change by the arrow keys. But for some angles, the picture look odd like this:

[image]

and after more rotations, it looks like this:
[image]

It seems the faces that was at the back are transparent. Why is that? How can I make this object to be printed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** The solution is to enable back-face culling via `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`. You may want to verify that your object's polygons are defined with the correct winding order and ensure back-face culling is set (`glCullFace(GL_BACK_FACE)`) if you don't intend to see inside the object.

---

**Original answer:**

The light is not touching the opposite side of the object and your ambient lighting is set to black:

```
 GLfloat black[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, black);
```

Try setting your ambient light to a dark grey color to roughly approximate the ambient light contribution of [global illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_illumination):

```
 GLfloat ambient[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
```

Comment: It still looks the same... Why the back side of the object display as black in the front? I don't need to see the black faces at all. I am looking straight at the object, and the light behind me...

Comment: What is your clear color? Also, is backface culling enabled? If this is true, perhaps the object's polygons have a winding order that defines the front face as the inner face instead of outer face. Perhaps try `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` as well.

Comment: Hmm, it look like I have forgot to enable the backface culling... After I have added `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` it works well. Thank you!

Comment: The more general solution is to request a depth buffer, and enable depth testing. You will get correct results with just backface culling as long as you're only drawing one single object that is convex. Beyond that, it will not be sufficient.